# Pick events not working in matplotlib with Anaconda/Spyder on Windows

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I have a script which generates an interactive plot which updates when the user clicks checkboxes and bars on a bar chart. Both work perfectly well on my Mac with Python installed via Homebrew and matplotlib via pip, but clicking the bars does nothing when run through Spyder/Anaconda on university Windows machines. The callback for pick events is as follows:

```
def bar_pick_handler(event):
    '''Called whenever a bar on the bar chart is clicked. Displays info
       for that place in the bottom right.'''
    # Find the x position of the bar that was clicked.
    rect = event.artist
    bar_x = rect.get_x()

    # Transform the position into an index for the x-tick label list and
    # get the name of the place that the bar represents.
    place_name = chart.get_xticklabels()[int(bar_x/5)].get_text()
    # Get the correspomding place dict.
    place_dict = next(p for p in all_places if p['name'] == place_name)

    # Set the place info text box text to show information about the selected
    # place.
    info_text = '''{name}
```

which is connected to pick events with `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', bar_pick_handler)` later. It seems that the GUI isn't registering pick events when run with Spyder on Windows, changing the callback to just print something does nothing. The checkboxes work fine.

Setup on Windows is Python 3.5.1, matplotlib 1.5.1. Spyder 2.3.8, pyt 4.11.4, qt 4.8.7.

I have a feeling it's a backend issue, but I don't know enough about Anaconda to get further.

Comment: Can you confirm that the versions of `python`, `pyqt`, `matplotlib` etc. match exactly on both os? Anaconda comes with its own packages and often they interfere with the ones you tried to install manually.

Comment: I've added the Windows versions, I'll check the mac ones when I get home, though I'm pretty sure they're different. I don't have Anaconda on my Mac, and I didn't install anything manually on the uni machines. Their environment does seem like a mess though, 2 versions of Anaconda and suchlike.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] of the issue. Just showing some code sniplet and saying that it doesn't work is not helpful. What you want is that someone is able to reproduce the issue and hence be able to help you solve it.

Comment: My apologies, I was quite stressed and fed up when I submitted the question. I'll update with a minimal example once I'm sure it reproduces the issue.